# Injecting and then using a method

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I'm toying with method injection but burning my fingers on this one.

There are two classes, cats and dogs. The dogs are trying to figure out the secret of the cats by swizzling the `speak` method. The dogs do figure out that the cats have a `catSecret` method but are unable to dynamically inject a replacement for it. Why?

The relevant methods on the `Dog` side are

```
- ( NSString * ) speak
{
    return @"Woof";
}

- ( NSString * ) wannabeCat
{
    return @"Meow?";
}

+ ( BOOL ) resolveInstanceMethod:( SEL ) aSelector
{
    NSString * s = NSStringFromSelector ( aSelector );

    if ( [s containsString:@"Secret"] )
    {
        NSLog ( @"Oops - the cats have a %@", s );
        
        IMP m = [Dog.class methodForSelector:@selector ( wannabeCat )];
        
        class_addMethod ( Dog.class, aSelector, m, "@@:" );
        
        NSLog ( @"\tAdded" );
        
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog ( @"Skipping %@", s );
        return [super resolveInstanceMethod:aSelector];
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Earlier I tried to do the same thing in the `forwardingTargetForSelector` method but after comments from Cy-4AH I moved it to `resolveInstanceMethod` which seems to be the right place to do it.

The dogs were hoping that after this, the `Dog` class has an added method but this is not working. It still terminates with a `'-[Dog catSecret]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` message. My question is - why is this not working?

On the `Cat` side this is the relevant pieces.

```
- ( NSString * ) catSecret
{
    return @"scratch";
}

- ( NSString * ) speak
{
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Miaau (%@)", self.catSecret] 
}
```

I was hoping to dynamically inject the `catSecret` selector with the `wannabeCat` implementation on the `Dog` side.

The output looks like this

```
2020-10-28 12:05:12.613324+0200 Swizzle[4786:119045] Oops - the cats have a catSecret
2020-10-28 12:05:12.613357+0200 Swizzle[4786:119045]    Added
2020-10-28 12:05:12.613434+0200 Swizzle[4786:119045] Skipping _forwardStackInvocation:
2020-10-28 12:05:12.613482+0200 Swizzle[4786:119045] -[Dog catSecret]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1006b2730
```

Comment: `forwardingTargetForSelector` is for forwarding target for selector, it's mean to find some one who able to perform selector. For dynamically adding implementation for selectors you need `resolveInstanceMethod:`

Comment: Yes - I was hoping to inject the method in ```forwardingTargetForSelector``` that is why I return ```self``` from there ... but I'll try do it in ```resolveInstanceMethod:``` ...

Comment: Try put your's test code inside `dyspatch_asynch`, may be you are trying to test is to early

Comment: I moved the code to ```+resolveInstanceMethod:``` and it then adds it no problem. I think this is the way to do it thanks, but it still ends up with unrecognised selector exception. I log the selectors it wants to resolve and also get a ```_forwardStackInvocation:``` in ```+resolveInstanceMethod``` which I don't know how to handle. I suppose I am just looking for a way to dynamically inject and then use a method and what I try is not working. The examples I've seen normally inject some known method but here the. method is *discovered* dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Cleaned up based on Cy-4AH comments.

The first, much bigger step was to move the method injection to the `resolveInstanceMethod` and I've edited the question to reflect this. This was also due to Cy-4AH, which by now I can almost type without error.

However, the final fix was a small one ... the way the code is in the question

```
IMP m = [Dog.class methodForSelector:@selector ( wannabeCat )];
```

refers to a class method, not an instance method. This must be changed to

```
IMP m = class_getMethodImplementation ( Dog.class, @selector ( wannabeCat ) );
```

to make it an instance method and then it works just fine, to the dogs' delight ...

For reference, the full new method becomes

```
+ ( BOOL ) resolveInstanceMethod:( SEL ) aSelector
{
    if ( [super resolveInstanceMethod:aSelector] )
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog ( @"Oops - the cats have a %@", NSStringFromSelector( aSelector ) );
        
        IMP m = class_getMethodImplementation ( Dog.class, @selector ( wannabeCat ) );
        
        class_addMethod ( Dog.class, aSelector, m, "@@:" );
        
        NSLog ( @"\tAdded" );
        
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need `class_getMethodImplementation(self, @selector ( wannabeCat ))` instead of `[[Dog alloc] init...`

Comment: Yes! Much cleaner thanks ... I've edited it into the answer.